# python pandas seperate string column in two by whitespace

Tags: python, pandas, replace, extract

I have a python pandas dataframe df with the following column "title":

```
title
This is the first title XY2547
This is the second title WWW48921
This is the third title  A2438999
This is another title 123
```

I need to split this column into two, the actual title and the irregular code in the end. Is there a way to split it by the last word behind the whitespace?
Please note that the last title has no code and the 123 is part of the title.

End Goal DF

```
title                             |  cleaned title            | code
This is the first title XY2547       This is the first title    XY2547
This is the second title WWW48921    This is the second title   WWW48921
This is the third title  A2438999    This is the third title    A2438999
This is another title 123            This is another title 123
```

I was thinking of something like

```
df['code'] = df.title.str.extract(r'_\s(\w)', expand=False)
```

This doesn't work.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [62]: df
Out[62]:
                               title
0     This is the first title XY2547
1  This is the second title WWW48921
2  This is the third title  A2438999
3         This is another title 123

In [63]: df[['cleaned_title', 'code']] = \
    ...:     df.title.str.extract(r'(.*?)\s+([A-Z]{1,}\d{3,})?$', expand=True)

In [64]: df
Out[64]:
                               title              cleaned_title      code
0     This is the first title XY2547    This is the first title    XY2547
1  This is the second title WWW48921   This is the second title  WWW48921
2  This is the third title  A2438999    This is the third title  A2438999
3         This is another title 123   This is another title 123       NaN
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining this portion r'(.*?)\s+(\w+\d+)' in more detail? Those are regular expressions, correct?I'm googling the heck out of them ...

Comment: @jeangelj, if you want you can use online RegEx explainer, like https://regex101.com/

Comment: @jeangelj, glad i could help :)

Comment: using this incredible regex explainer, do I understand this correctly; I am extracting a string based on regex (that's the r) - everything after a whitespace and in the end (that's the (.?)\s and $) that includes a letter and at least 3 digits?

Comment: Wow! RegEx explainer ftw.

Comment: @jeangelj, yes, i think you understand it correctly

Comment: @jeangelj its 1 or more letters followed by 3 or more digits.  Use this knowledge to tailor it to exactly what you need.

Comment: Thank you; I understand now

Answer (score 1):

## Solution `#1`

[`str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) can be of use here.  It splits `n` number of times, starting from the right of the string.

We can then `join` the results with `df`

```
df.join(
    df.title.str.rsplit(n=1, expand=True).rename(
        columns={0: 'cleaned title', 1: 'code'}
    )
)

                               title             cleaned title      code
0     This is the first title XY2547   This is the first title    XY2547
1  This is the second title WWW48921  This is the second title  WWW48921
2  This is the third title  A2438999   This is the third title  A2438999
3         This is another title 123      This is another title       123
```

## Solution `#2`

To avoid the `123` being interpreted as a code, you must apply some additional logic that you did not provide.  @MaxU was gracious enough to embed his logic in the regex.

My `regex` solution would look like this.
***plan***

- use `'?P<name>'` to name the column that is produed
- match only upper case letters and any digits with `'[A-Z0-9]'`
- make sure there are 4 or more with `'{4,}'`
- match from the beginning `'^'` to the end `'$'`
- make sure `'.*'` isn't greedy with `'.*?'`

---

```
regex = '^(?P<cleaned_title>.*?)\s*(?P<code>[A-Z0-9]{4,})?$'
df.join(df.title.str.extract(regex, expand=True))

                               title              cleaned_title      code
0     This is the first title XY2547    This is the first title    XY2547
1  This is the second title WWW48921   This is the second title  WWW48921
2  This is the third title  A2438999    This is the third title  A2438999
3          This is another title 123  This is another title 123       NaN
```

Comment: Thank you - in the example above, it does make "123" a value in the separate column, even though it's part of the title, because the code is missing, but I guess that has to be a manual cleanup.Is there a way to specify though that it should only separate the least word out if it contains numbers?

Comment: Thank you so much - I just upvoted this answer and am testing it right now; also thank you very much for the regex explanation

Comment: @jeangelj no problem, glad I could help.

Comment: as always, beyond helpful! THANK YOU

Comment: @piRSquared, i just wanted to add some explanations for the RegEx and then i saw your update - it's perfect. I couldn't explain it better

Comment: thank you; I always upvote @piRSquared - best and fastest answers on stackoverflow!

Comment: sorry guys, didn't notice that :)